# How do I specify a date range when searching Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

I visit the Google Groups webpage. I enter a search term. Results are returned. There used to be a menu for me to select a date range. That seems to have gone.

i: is there a menu to enter a date range?

ii: are there search parameters that control the date range?

For my example I want anything before 2005/01/01 and nothing after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search helper/form only is displayed when the user is in a page for an specific group but not at http://groups.google.com

The search operator for posts before a date is `before:`

I.E. [before:2005/01/01](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/before$3A2005$2F01$2F01)

For other search terms, go to [Search Terms - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2371405)